# How do i create an onclick event for each element in an array to redirect to a url?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of images that loop through each second. My goal is to have the user click on an image they find interesting, and the browser redirect to a url. I'm rusty on JS so, I'm not sure how to proceed with the logic. I presume I need to create a function or a for loop that utilize each array index? Any help on this would be great.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body style="text-align: center;">
<script type="text/javascript">

    var favPodcasts = [

        "imgs/theread.jpg",
        "imgs/jadexd.jpg",
        "imgs/devtea1.jpg",
        "imgs/pstp.png",
        "imgs/ahb3.jpg",
        "imgs/jsair.png",
        "imgs/sp1.jpg",
];

var i = 0;

function slideshow() {

    document.getElementById('podcasts').src = favPodcasts[i];

    if (i < favPodcasts.length - 1) {

        i++;
    }
        else {
            i = 0;
        }

        setTimeout("slideshow()", 3000);
    }

</script>

<img style="border: black solid 5px; margin-top:10%;" id="podcasts" 
width="300px" height="300px" />

<script> slideshow(); </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the `<image>` tag inside an `<a>` tag, then change the `src` and `href` respectively

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body style="text-align: center;">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var favPodcasts = [
            { image: "imgs/theread.jpg", url: 'http://www.example1.com' },
            { image: "imgs/jadexd.jpg", url: 'http://www.example2.com' },
            { image: "imgs/devtea1.jpg", url: 'http://www.example3.com' },
            { image: "imgs/pstp.png", url: 'http://www.example4.com' },
            { image: "imgs/ahb3.jpg", url: 'http://www.example5.com' },
            { image: "imgs/jsair.png", url: 'http://www.example6.com' },
            { image: "imgs/sp1.jpg", url: 'http://www.example7.com' },
        ];

        var i = 0;

        function slideshow() {

            var link = document.getElementById('podcasts');
            link.href = favPodcasts[i]['url']
            link.children[0].src = favPodcasts[i]['image'];

            if (i < favPodcasts.length - 1) {

                i++;
            }
            else {
                i = 0;
            }

            setTimeout("slideshow()", 3000);
        }

    </script>

    <a id="podcasts" href="">
        <img style="border: black solid 5px; margin-top:10%;" width="300px" height="300px" />
    </a>

    <script> slideshow(); </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Question can you explain the statements: link.href = favPodcasts[i]['url']
            link.children[0].src = favPodcasts[i]['image'];

Comment: The first statement is to update the <a href=""> to url inside the favPodcasts array. The second statement is to update the <img src=""> to image path inside the favPodcasts array

Answer (score 0):

```
var favPodcasts = [

    "imgs/theread.jpg",
    "imgs/jadexd.jpg",
    "imgs/devtea1.jpg",
    "imgs/pstp.png",
    "imgs/ahb3.jpg",
    "imgs/jsair.png",
    "imgs/sp1.jpg",
];
var url_list = [

        "url1",
        "url2",
        "url3",
        "url4",
        "url5",
        "url6",
        "url7",
];

var i = 0;

function slideshow() {

    document.getElementById('podcasts').src = favPodcasts[i];
    document.getElementById('link1').href = url_list[i];
    if (i < favPodcasts.length - 1) {

        i++;
    }
    else {
        i = 0;
    }

    setTimeout("slideshow()", 3000);
}


<a href="" id="link1"><img src="" id="podcasts"/></a>
```

Comment: <a href="" id="link1"><img src="" id="podcasts"/></a>

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap the thumbnail in a link and put the urls and images in the same object for easy maintenance. I prefer setInterval to calling the setTimeout method repeatedly, but it works either way.

```js
const favPodcasts = [{
    src: "https://picsum.photos/300/?image=0",
    url: "www.google.com"
  },
  {
    src: "https://picsum.photos/300/300/?image=1",
    url: "www.facebook.com"
  },
  {
    src: "https://picsum.photos/300/300/?image=2",
    url: "www.twitter.com"
  }
];

const podcastImage = document.getElementById('podcast-thumbnail');
const podcastLink = document.getElementById('podcast-link')
let i = favPodcasts.length;

function slideshow() {

  if (++i >= favPodcasts.length) {
    i = 0;
  }
  
  podcastImage.src = favPodcasts[i].src;
  podcastLink.href = favPodcasts[i].url;

}

setInterval(slideshow, 3000);
slideshow();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body style="text-align: center;">

  <a href="#" target="_blank" id="podcast-link">
    <img style="border: black solid 5px; margin-top:10%;" id="podcast-thumbnail" width="300px" height="300px" />
  </a>

</body>

</html>
```